# git - "debug" branch, merge "fix" branch without "debug"

Tags: git

I have a buggy `master` branch that I need to debug. To do that, I want to insert a bunch of debug procedures (e.g., printing variables), pin point the bug and apply fixes. Later, I want to merge the fixes into the `master` branch, but I want not to skip debug changes.

```
# create debug branch
git checkout -b debug

# ...
# edit sources and add debug prints
# ...

# commit debug changes
git commit --all

# create branch for the fix
git checkout -b fix
```

Now do the proper fix and commit

```
git commit --all
```

Go to `master` branch...

```
git checkout master
```

...and merge with the fix *without* debug changes

```
git merge fix # <-- wrong, will merge debug changes as well
```

How to merge `fix` without `debug`?

Comment: do you need the changes done in debug for the branch fix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is the 'onto' option of 'git rebase' (see 'git help rebase').  From what you described it would be:

```
git rebase --onto master debug fix
```

This actually re-roots the (from 'fix', to 'debug') commits at master.  You still have the fix branch.  To complete rework, follow up with:

```
git checkout master
git merge fix
```

Comment: Worth noting that after this `--onto` operation, `fix` branch contains  fixed code *without* debug code.

Comment: Right, that is what I meant by my 're-roots' statement.

Comment: Ah.  By '(fix-debug)' you actually *mean* 'fix *minus* debug'

Comment: I reworded to make it explicit.  Thanks.